# Get image dimensions (not resolution) from PDF file

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file with text and an image. Looking at the document properties, I can find out the dimensions of the document (e.g. 297 mm x 210 mm). What I'd like to know are the dimensions of the image. Not the resolution (in pixels), but how large it would appear on paper if I printed the PDF file.

How can I get that information from the digital file, without printing it and measuring it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

It ultimately depends on how the image is used by the PDF file. The [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) contains an example on p. 209 of how to position an image on a page:

> EXAMPLE This example defines an image 256 samples wide by 256 high, with 8 bits per sample in the DeviceGray colour space. It paints the image on a page with its lower-left corner positioned at coordinates (45, 140) in current user space and scaled to a width and height of 132 user space units.

```
% Page object
20 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Parent 1 0 R
  /Resources 21 0 R 
  /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] 
  /Contents 23 0 R
>> endobj

% Resource dictionary for page
21 0 obj
<< 
  /ProcSet [ /PDF /ImageB ]
  /XObject << /Im1 22 0 R >> 
>> endobj 

% Image XObject
22 0 obj
<<
  /Type /XObject
  /Subtype /Image
  /Width 256
  /Height 256
  /ColorSpace /DeviceGray /BitsPerComponent 8 /Length 83183
  /Filter /ASCII85Decode 
>>
stream 9LhZI9h\GY9i+bb;,p:e;G9SP92/)X9MJ>^:f14d;,U(X8P;cO;G9e];c$=k9Mn\]
...Image data representing 65,536 samples...
8P;cO;G9e];c$=k9Mn\]~>
endstream
endobj

% Contents of page
23 0 obj
<< 
  /Length 56 
>>
stream 
  q
  132 0 0 132 45 140 cm   % Translate to (45,140) and scale by 132
  /Im1 Do                 % Paint image
  Q
endstream endobj
```

The last object (number 23) contains a command to translate and scale the image, and paint it. The commands in your PDF may look similarly (or more complicated), you'll need to inspect them to find out where and in what size the image is painted.

You can look at your PDF file by decompressing the streams e.g. with `mutool`, and opening it in a text editor.